# How to connect appengine application running on local server with GCM server

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I have created client-server project to figure out GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) service. It is working well on my first try when i deployed :--

1)Android App to my device.

2)Appengine App to Appengine server.

But i am missing one thing what if i need to make changes to project mainly on appengine app. Every time i need to deploy to appengine server to test it whether its working properly or not. Its takes lots of time.

How to test LOCAL appengine server app (as server) with android DEVICE (as client)  not emulator....?? **I mean how aappengine application running on local server connects to GCM server (somewhere on WWW) resulting push notification on my android device...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send messages to the GCM server you don't even need to run a local server. Any application running on your local computer that can connect to the internet and send an HTTP POST request can send a message to the GCM server, which will be sent to your device (assuming you use the correct registration ID).

You only need a local server if you want your Android app to send the registration ID to your local computer.

This means you can easily test most of your server code locally without setting up a local server.