# Where to put my php file?

Tags: javascript, php, android, mysql, database

I am trying to make a sign up activity on android and I am using a mysql database to store the data. On all the examples I have seen the http post goes to a ip address and then finds the php file. Can I just put the php file somewhere in the android app folder and access it from there, or do I have to find a host for it?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between the client and the server. In particular, you do _not_ want clients to have access to your database.

Comment: I know I don't but when they finish typing in all their info and click sign up shouldn't it just post it to the database? That really isn't giving them access to it, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The php code, specially for tasks such as [sign up](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-code-a-signup-form-with-email-confirmation--net-6860), should never be placed on the client side or embedded with the front end application, but instead be placed on the server side hidden from the user for the sake of safety of your database/application. If you are only considering to put your php with your Android app together for the case you need to test it, and eventually doesn't have access to a server, you may then consider using [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-testdeploy), as it allows you to emulate a server [locally](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-testdeploy) without the need of a [server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533741/how-to-connect-appengine-application-running-on-local-server-with-gcm-server). Here you find some info about [Amazon's RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188373/connecting-android-app-to-amazon-rds).

You can put you php in the same directory you place your index.html file, i.e. in the root public directory of your domain. To load it to the Amazon, you can use the cPanel or the Filezilla or any other panel you wish among the options Amazon put available for their users.

In the case Amazon doesn't provide a place to put your php, as a suggestion, you can get a host that allows you to have a static ip accessing it thorough an easy to remember url address - for [free](http://www.noip.com/). It is quite useful specially for making tests. Still if you decide at some point to have a personalized domain name registered, there are also some other good [options](http://www.hostgator.com/) to compare.

Comment: Alright, where would I put the php file then, I am using an Amazon database service. Do I find a way to load it up onto that?

Comment: Well I don't have a site up I am just using their Relational Database Service. I will look but I do not think that they give me a directory like that.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need `jQuery`, when doing the POST request,`PHP` connects to the database get the data and return it to your app.

So to answer your question you should put the `PHP` in the same server where `mysql` runs.

Comment: ok cool I am using Amazon's RDS do you know anything about that?

Comment: No I don't know that.